# PHP Post CheckBox Returned Empty Array

Tags: php, html

I have used this to collect the checkbox value array.

```
    <form action="example.php" method="post" name="deleteform">
    <input type="submit" value="delete"/>

    <table>
    <?php

    foreach ($memArray as $row) {
       echo "<tr align=\"center\">
       <td><input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"".$row['cus_id']."\" name=\"del[]\" /></td>";   
         echo "</tr>";  
    }
    ?>
    </table>
</form
```

>

if the form is Posted, then do

```
    $delArray = $_POST['del'];

    print_r($delArray);
```

But the result returned Array, but nothing inside

I have changed name=del instead of name=del[], and it works . But when i add the [] back it return empty array

Comment: Checkboxes which are not checked do not get submitted with the rest of the form.

Comment: check form method.. is that post or you have set it to get..?

Comment: It's inside a form, i m using post method.

Comment: try `print_r`ing the entire `$_POST` variable. See what you can find there.

Comment: it returned Array ( [del] => Array [deleteinfo] => true )

Comment: You missed "; after <td><input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"".$row['cus_id']."\" name=\"del[]\" /></td>

Comment: Not working. Please help

Comment: My suggestion Try to use echo '<tr><td><input type="del[]"></td></tr>'; Try to avoid \"

Answer (score 2):

you should check 2 things.

first is form method. whether it is post or get..

second when you submit the page, check box is checked or not. if it is not checked then you can not have array in $_GET or in $_POST

Comment: Both checked. I m using post and the check box is checked

Comment: Thanks. But still not working, I have changed name=del instead of name=del[], and it works . But when i add the [] back it return empty array

Comment: this is something strange but happy that you got the solution.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is your code, though i have made changes to loop. checkbox.php is the current file name.

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['delete']))
    {
        print_r($_POST['del']);
    }
?>
<form action="checkbox.php" method="post" name="deleteform">
<input type="submit" value="delete" name="delete"/>

<table>
<?php

for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
   echo "<tr align=\"center\">
   <td><input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"".$i."\" name=\"del[]\" /></td>";
     echo "</tr>";  
}
?>
</table>
```

Compare it with your code. On submit you'll get definitely get array.

Comment: Thanks. But still not working, I have changed name=del instead of name=del[], and it works . But when i add the [] back it return empty array

Comment: My advice please go thru your whole codding.